# Ошибка вставки изображения после копирования

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

Воспользовался [данной](http://brianlagunas.com/wpf-copy-uielement-as-image-to-clipboard/) реализацией для копировния окна в буфер обмена. В целом копирование и вставка работает, но не везде. Например вставка в Paint работает, а вот вставка, например, в сообщение Вконтакте не работает, хотя если скопировать скриншот вновь из Paint и вставить в сообщение ВК то всё работает. В чём тут может быть проблема?

**UPD:** Даже если просто получить изображение из буфера через `GetImage()` и сразу полученое передать в `SetImage()`, проблема остаётся.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что вставить в сообщение ВК картинку нельзя. Можно вставить только файл.

Методика "копирования через Paint", на самом деле, заключается в сохранении скриншота в файл.

Можно такое преобразование сделать и на стороне программы. Для этого надо сохранить изображение во временный файл, после чего воспользоваться методом [`Clipboard.SetFileDropList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.clipboard.setfiledroplist(v=vs.110).aspx).

Есть вариант копировать в буфер обмена файл и изображение одновременно, чтобы программа-получатель выбрала более удобный вариант. Это делается через [`Clipboard.SetDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms597039(v=vs.110).aspx). Перед этим надо сформировать [`DataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.dataobject(v=vs.110).aspx), положив в него картинку и файл.

Comment: Cпасибо, думаю это как раз то что нужно. Но тогда хочу уточнить. В этом случае в `Clipboard.SetDataObject` нужно передавать массив `DataObject`,  или в  `DataObject` присвоить массив `object`?

Comment: Откуда у вас в мыслях вообще взялись массивы?.. Я что-то про них говорил?..

Comment: Ну положить в объект 2 объекта, я могу предположить только с в случаях специальной для этого функций, либо с помощью присвоения массива

Comment: Что вам мешает сначала вызвать `SetImage`, а потом `SetFileDropList`? У `DataObject`, в отличии от `Clipboard`, Set-методы не очищают то что там лежало ранее.

Comment: Вот это я и хотел уточнить. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Ещё один вопрос. Я так понял нужно сохранить обработанный скриншот в файл на диск и указать к нему путь в `SetFileDropList`? Путь указываю, он существует, но вставка так же не рабочая. Возможно я что то не понял. [Вот](http://cs630628.vk.me/v630628173/2701c/cxZz7t-pknY.jpg) как я делал.